# Angular-cli build (ng build) on Teamcity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, teamcity

I hope someone has already done this.
I am trying to set up a continuous build in teamcity for one my angular 2 project.
After done some research and I have followed the steps as follows:

1. Build Step1: installed the jonnyzzz.node plugin for the teamcity. (Now I can pick Node.js NPM from Runner type)
    npm commands: I added install command
2. Build Step 2: Another Node.js NPM and npm commands: install -g angular-cli
   So far so good
3. Now I wanted to build ng build as the third step and I am really stuck as I have no way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have resolved my own problem.  I have modified the npm package.json and added ng build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get ng build work from nodejs plugin for Team city, I have modified the package.json file.
In start replace the value with "ng build".
And from team city, npm build command will trigger the ng build command.

Comment: Solved my problem on TFS also, Thanks.

Comment: Awesome.  I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: @Ravimaran Can we build the angular-cli application without installing the  jonnyzzz.node plugin

Comment: Hi Indra257, 
I believe you need node plugin in the team city to do npm build. This plugin actually worked very well.

Comment: @Ravimaran I am trying little different. I am actually taking the bundles that were created by ng build and trying to deploy them to octopus. So steps that I followed, i) Use NugetPack and provide the nuspec file, which will create .nupkg. After that do I have to run Nuget Publish to push it to my octopus

Comment: @Ravimaran You mean node plugin or  jonnyzzz.node plugin

Answer (score 10):

Rather than changing your package.json you can use the node.js NPM plugin and the run command:

```
run build
```

build it not a default command for NPM so you need the 'run build' which is mapped to ng build in default ng-cli package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DCcq.png)

Comment: To be clear, if you install node and have node and npm in the path, you can run `npm run build`, which in long form is actually `npm run-script build`. The `run` or `run-script` is required because npm doesn't really know about 'build' or other targets natively. If you are using nvm for Windows instead of the TeamCity.node plugin, you can call `npm run-script build` from cmd or PowerShell.

Comment: Better solution IMO, no need to change your source code to cope with your build agent. +1

Answer (score 1):

First start with the build agents where you can edit the buildAgent.properties file and define 3 environment variables. You should have the surrounding single quotes here or later on in your build definitions:

```
env.exec.node='C\:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe'
env.exec.npm='C\:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
env.exec.ng='%env.APPDATA%\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng'
```

The `%env.APPDATA%` is used here but some setups may be installed on the Program Files, in most cases the AppData will be the one to take.

Next you can define build steps for your project. Create these new build steps of type Powershell and set Script as Source Code. Inside the Script Source you can now enter:

> Install Angular CLI

```
& %env.exec.node% %env.exec.npm% install -g @angular/cli
```

> Install node_modules folder

```
& %env.exec.node% %env.exec.npm% install
```

> Build and publish solution

```
& %env.exec.node% %env.exec.ng% build --environment '%env.build.environment%' --scripts-prepend-node-path
```

After this step production builds will create your dist folder which you can include into your Artifacts paths so you have access to it should you want to create seperate Deployment type build configurations

Some considerations to take into account here:

- You could define the variables inside your  however
  different paths may be used on the build agents, which would brake
  your builds
- Make sure you have proper Clean-Up Rules in place, since node_modules
  folders can get big really fast

Hope it helps out someone!